# Repeating python code multiple times - is there a way of condensing it?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got multiple blocks of code which I need to repeat multiple times (in sequence). Here's an example of two blocks (there are many more).

```
#cold winter
wincoldseq = [] #blank list

ran_yr = np.random.choice(coldwinter,1) #choose a random year from the extreme winter variable
wincoldseq += [(ran_yr[0], 1)] #take the random year and the value '1' for winter to sample from 

for item in wincoldseq: #item is a tuple with year and season, ***seq is all year and season pairs for the variable
    projection.append(extremecold.query("Year == %d and Season == '%d'" % item))
```

followed by

```
#wet spring
sprwetseq = [] #blank list

ran_yr = np.random.choice(wetspring,1) #choose a random year from the extreme winter variable
sprwetseq += [(ran_yr[0], 2)] #take the random year and the value '2' for spring to sample from 

for item in sprwetseq: #item is a tuple with year and season, ***seq is all year and season pairs for the variable
    projection.append(extremewet.query("Year == %d and Season == '%d'" % item))
```

Instead of copying and pasting these multiple times, is there a way of condensing each block into a single variable? I've tried defining functions but as the code blocks don't have arguments it didn't make sense.

Comment: is there such a thing as a function in python?

Comment: @matpol erm... yes?

Comment: Functions without parameters are fine.

Comment: *"as the code blocks don't have arguments"* - they sort of do, the name of the list, the variable to choose from and the query could all be parameterised.

Comment: why don't you just create a function yourself?

Comment: Total novice here - couldn't see how this would be done for these blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just extract this out into a function, to avoid repeating code. For example:

```
def do_something_with(projection, data, input_list)
    items = []

    ran_yr = np.random.choice(input_list, 1)
    items += [(ran_yr[0], 1)]

    for item in output:
        projection.append(data.query("Year == %d and Season == '%d'" % item)) 

do_something_with(projection, sprwetseq, extremewet)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you just make it a function.  For instance:

```
def spring():
    sprwetseq = [] #blank list

    ran_yr = np.random.choice(wetspring,1) #choose a random year from the extreme winter variable
    sprwetseq += [(ran_yr[0], 2)] #take the random year and the value '2' for spring to sample from 

    for item in sprwetseq: #item is a tuple with year and season, ***seq is all year and season pairs for the variable
        projection.append(extremewet.query("Year == %d and Season == '%d'" % item))
```

I don't see how it would not make sense to put it into a function.

Hope this helps,

KittyKatCoder